# Can't get path to image in HTML

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

Alright, I have a file named slider.php which contains a bootstrap slider and I'm inserting pictures inside the slider but I can't figure out the correct way of writing the path to the pictures

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="item active">
      <img class="slide-image" src="" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
      <img class="slide-image" src="" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
      <img class="slide-image" src="" alt="">
  </div>
```

The slider.php is in this location **ecomcopy/resources/front/slider.php**
and the pictures are in **ecomcopy/resources/img/**

I tried everything and I can't get the correct pictures path

Can someone help?

Comment: I think it's only 2 up: `../../resources/img/yourimage.png`.

Comment: Neither one is working...

Comment: Actually only needs 1. See my answer below.

Comment: Guys I'm sorry I wrote the wrong path, it's ecomcopy/resources/templates/front/slider.php and ecomcopy/resources/templates/img

Comment: @VBCoding just use ./yourimage.png

Comment: is that file `slider.php` included by some other php file/script or is it actually the page you are calling in your browser?

Answer (score 0):

The way paths work is to go "up" to parent folders until you're at a common ancestor. Then go back down naming folders until you get to the file you're referencing.

```
ecomcopy/resources/front/slider.php
ecomcopy/resources/front/            (start)
ecomcopy/resources/                  (up 1) ../
ecomcopy/resources/templates/        (down to folder) templates/
ecomcopy/resources/templates/img/    (down to folder) img/
ecomcopy/resources/templates/img/yourimage.png
                                     (down to file) yourimage.png

result: ../templates/img/yourimage.png
```

Comment: so, now it's going to be ../templates/img/myimage.png?

Comment: Sorry--mispasted the path. That make more sense? You can move up by adding `../` and down by adding `folder-name/` as much as you want to move around the folders and find your file.

Comment: Still, it's not working, my images aren't showing in the slider, i've been ripping the hair out of my head for hours now and i just don't know what to do...

Comment: Make sure the images are in the path you think they are. Try putting that path after the domain of the site (`http://localhost/templates/img/myimage.png`) and make sure that can see the image.

Answer (score 0):

should be `../../img/image_name.png`

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier (at least on a live server setting) to just specify *absolute paths* for your URLs.

For example, the following HTML is all that is needed to serve your images:

```
<img src="/ecomcopy/resources/templates/img/yourimage.png" />
```

There is no real need to worry about complicated relative file paths.